# iOS, setTransform overridden by setFrame? Transform not re-drawing after setFrame is re-run

Tags: ios, uiview, screen-orientation, cgaffinetransform

**My transform does not draw after the frame is redrawn with setFrame.**

I'm scaling a view when the orientation changes using setFrame. But this view also needs to change position depending on a `BOOL` argument: *On = up in view, off = down off screen*. I use `setTransform` to adjust the position of the view.

First I draw the view by doing a `setFrame`. This draws the view 100 points just off screen at the bottom. Then I set a transform (-100 on the ty) to bring it up into the view points (as long as the `BOOL` is set to `TRUE`, else the transform is 0 and the view is off screen).

```
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100)];
[view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -100)]
```

This works fine, as expected, but when change orientation, and this code is re-run (to re-size the view) the transform does not draw, even though it is Logged as being the transform of the view. In other words the view is just off screen, as if the transform.ty was 0.

```
Log message before re-draw: view.transform.ty -10.000000
Log message after re-draw: view.transform.ty -10.000000
```

Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A view's `frame` is a value that is *derived* from three fundamental values: `bounds`, `center`, and `transform`. The setter for `frame` tries to do the right thing by reversing the process, but it can't always work correctly when a non-identity `transform` is set.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5) is pretty clear on this point:

> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of
>   this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.
>
> ...
>
> If the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value
>   of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that
>   case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust
>   the size using the bounds property instead.

Since your `transform` only translates the view, I don't see any reason to use it at all. Just change the origin of the view's frame:

```
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100)];
```